# Simples Differences CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Sorry by noob question, but what is the difference between:

```
a.highlight{
color: blue;
}
```

and

```
.highlight a{
color: blue;
}
```

markup:

```
 <a href="#" class="highlight">Link</a>
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a.highlight
```

This will select anchor with class `highlight`

when:

```
.highlight a
```

will select anchor which is **descendant** of an element with class `highlight`

Comment: Not just a child, a [descendent](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Answer (score 2):

a.highlight selects all a element with that class. .highlight a selects all a element that are descendants of elements that have that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
  a.highlight{
        color: blue;
  }
```

is an anchor with the class highlight

```
  .highlight a{
        color: blue;
  }
```

Edit:

is an anchor contained by something with the class "highlight"

for your markup you'll need the first rule.

Comment: replace the sentence below the second code block with "is an anchor contained by something with the class "highlight"". At the moment your answer is wrong.

Comment: Replaced. Forgive me for the wrong sentence :)

Answer (score -4):

In fact there's no difference in these two statements. Difference can be found later when, for example you'll need to style several links in block with .highlight class - then choose second example. But if you have no block but need only to style a link - then better use first example instead.

Comment: Sure there is a difference. The second doesn't target the markup provided.